# Materialize JS 'classList' of undefined on tabs

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm using Materialize js, and for some reason I just started receiving this error, but I can't seem to find where I made the mistake.

[image]

HTML:

```
       <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding:0px;">
        
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li class="tab col-sm-3"><a class="active" href="#customer">Customer</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col-sm-3 isAdmin"><a href="#case">Case</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col-sm-3 isAdmin"><a href="#admin">Admin</a></li>
                    <li class="tab col-sm-3 isManager"><a href="#manager">Manager</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                
                <form id="caseform">
                <div id="customer" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                <div id="case" class="col-sm-12 active"></div>
                <div id="admin" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                <div id="manager" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
                            
        </div>
```

I`m initiating it in the document ready

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.tab').tabs() //this is the jquery.custom.js line 100 from error
);
```

The error line 4204 from the materialize.js is 4204. Which reads:

```
    this.$tabLinks.removeClass('active');
    this.$activeTabLink[0].classList.add('active');
```

The `this.$activeTabLink[0].classList.add('active')` is coming up as 0 length, but I believe I'm using the correct classes and nesting with the ul.tabs

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/v1-dev/dist/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/v1-dev/dist/js/materialize.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('.tab').tabs()
})
</script>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                                
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <ul class="tabs">
                            <li class="tab col-sm-3"><a class="active" href="#customer">Customer</a></li>
                            <li class="tab col-sm-3 isAdmin"><a href="#case">Case</a></li>
                            <li class="tab col-sm-3 isAdmin"><a href="#admin">Admin</a></li>
                            <li class="tab col-sm-3 isManager"><a href="#manager">Manager</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <form id="caseform">
                        <div id="customer" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                        <div id="case" class="col-sm-12 active"></div>
                        <div id="admin" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                        <div id="manager" class="col-sm-12"></div>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you replicate that behaviour in your demo code ?

Comment: All scripts should be below the HTML, before the closing body tag. You are calling an initialisation on an element that hasn't been rendered yet.

Comment: @SeanDoherty, sorry, yes, I have the scripts at the bottom of the page.

I couldn't find the answer to this, so I just wrote out the Tabs manually.
Thanks anyways.